# React-Stripe-Elements handleCardPayment with saved card

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am switching to payment intents and am trying to reuse a saved card. (react-stripe-elements)

This works quite well right now and instead of

```
stripe.handleCardPayment(intentData.client_secret);
```

(as suggested in the docs) I am using the following, because this worked.

```
stripe.confirmPaymentIntent(intentData.client_secret)
```

With the first one I always got an error, that the card number is not filled out - seems like it always takes the react-elements-form that is on the same page as a basis.

It worked and I could pay with my saved cards until now, but now I tested it, with the "requires auth on all transactions" card: 4000002760003184

When I use confirmPaymentIntent it just gets stuck on the status: [status] => requires_source_action

How would I go about and show the "confirmation" dialog, as it did with the handleCardPayment method, in case it is needed?

The transactions are all happening on the page and are triggered via react-stripe-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like react-stripe-elements will always take the `Elements` form context, whenever you have a form initialized (which I had on the same page) and you use the `stripe` prop.

This is pretty neat, when you fill out the form to add a new credit card, but really annoying, when you don't want to use form data, but your saved card.

I asked the stripe support and they told me, that there is no way to get around this, so I looked around a little more and found, that react-stripe-elements is just using the normal Stripe JS SDk and thereby the `window.Stripe` object should be available (out of the  content) to do this easily.

So this is how I solved it for us:

```js
const { stripe } = this.props;

// if we use a saved payment method and the Stripe obj is available
if (isSavedPaymentMethod && typeof Stripe !== 'undefined') {
  // don't use the context bound stripe from react-stripe-elements, but the uninitialized Stripe and pass your key
  const stripeOutofBound = Stripe(STRIPE_API_KEY);
  await stripeOutofBound.handleCardPayment(
    intentData.client_secret,
  );
} else {
  // otherwise use the react-stripe-elements prop directly, that passes the new credit card form data
  await stripe.handleCardPayment(
    intentData.client_secret,
  );
}
```